# What is a Stackable Profession™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is based on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).</sub>

---

If a profession meets certain criteria, I call it a Stackable Profession™. Here are some examples:

| Stackable Profession™ | Non-Stackable Profession™ |
| --- | --- |
| Gardening | Farming |
| Photography | Interior Design |
| Academia | Marketing |
| Carpentry/Woodworking | Architecture |
| Writing | Publishing (Books) |
| Cooking | Taste-Testing |
| Software Engineering | Waitering |
| Electrical Engineering | Patent Inspection |

CSV:

```
Stackable Profession™,Non-Stackable Profession™
Gardening,Farming
Photography,Interior Design
Academia,Marketing
Carpentry/Woodworking,Architecture
Writing,Publishing (Books)
Cooking,Taste-Testing
Software Engineering,Waitering
Electrical Engineering,Patent Inspection
```

Can you figure out which professions are Stackable Professions™?

*Note: each profession stands on its own - that is, you can determine whether or not it is a Stackable Profession™ just from itself.*

I apologize if this is too easy or too hard - this is my first post here, though I've been hanging around for a while.

Comment: The obvious answer would be Rot13(nal cebsrffvba jvgu n Fgnpx Rkpunatr fvgr, ohg Cbyvgvpf qbrfa'g svg gur cnggrea).

Comment: @F1Krazy Realized that at the last second, I had changed it in the CSV but forgot to in the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Stackable Profession is

> any profession that has its own dedicated Stack Exchange site.

Specifically:

> - Gardening has [Gardening and Landscaping.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)
>  - Photography has [Photography.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)
>  - Academia has [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)
>  - Carpentry/Woodworking has [Woodworking.SE](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/)
>  - Writing has [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/)
>  - Cooking has [Seasoned Advice aka Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)
>  - Software Engineering has [Software Engineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
>  - Electrical Engineering has [Electrical Engineering.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)